# Plone: filtered view of Unauthorized exceptions

Tags: exception, plone, plone-4.x

In my Plone site, `Unauthorized` exceptions are quite common; most of the time they mean, "Please log in, because the requested content is not available for anonymous users".  Normally, those exceptions are ignored for the error log (`/prefs_error_log_form`).

However, sometimes such exceptions are supposed *not* to be raised, and there is some problem which causes a malfunction. Is it possible to get a filtered list of `Unauthorized` exceptions, e.g. filtered by a certain path?

Comment: Hi - at some point I may not be able to keep crossposting your questions to the forum. It would be great if you just posted your questions there to begin with! https://community.plone.org/t/stack-overflow-plone-filtered-view-of-unautorized-exceptions/4476

Answer (score 1):

If you install something like iw.rejectanonymous, you should be able to log all Unauthorized exceptions and only get authenticated users trying to access something they shouldn't.